# How to host multiple WordPress site on single AWS EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have created an Ubuntu server on AWS. I have completed setup of wordpress and  address is http://52.43.10.81 right now it is working.

This is my public ip 52.43.10.81. Now I want host another wordpress website on this server. For hosting another wordpress website on this server, I have create database but when I setup wordpress on this server I have add database name and I have used previous username and password which I have used in previous wordpress site.

I am getting error when i am installing WordPress

[image]

Comment: you need to add **privileges** to the user in order to allow him access the databese. It's not enough to create a user. And it's more safe to create also a new database, don't use the same one for the two sites if you are not experienced